# Menu at the bottom

Tags: error

I am currently working on SPD with a v4.master master page, I inserted an image as body and I did get rid of the quick menus and recycle bin and that stuff (I guess) but when I publish it I get this at the bottom:

> Enable anonymous access
>
> Anonymous access allows users to view the pages on this site without logging in. 
> This is useful when creating internet facing sites or sites where you want everyone to have access to read the content without editing.
> Manage navigation
> Change the navigation links in this site.
> Go to master page gallery 
> Change the page layouts and master page of this site collection.
> Manage site content and structure
> Reorganize content and structure in this site collection.
> Set up multilingual support
> Use the variations feature to manage multi-lingual sites and pages.
> Add users to the Approvers and Members groups
> Users in the Approvers group can publish pages, images, and documents in this site. Users in the Members group can create and edit pages, and they can upload images and documents, but they cannot publish the pages, images, or documents. Workflow is enabled in the Pages library, and content approval is enabled in the Documents and Images libraries.

My question is how to get rid of that "menu"?

Comment: Isn't this just the default content of your page? Try to edit the page in the browser.

Comment: Yes it is, but I would like to get rid of it or hide it, I was not able to do it just by editing the page

Answer (score 0):

Your content is not stored in your `.master` it's stored in the corresponding item in the page library. Check your URL for the filename (i.E. default.aspx) and navigate to your page library.

If you edit the item for your page you can see a set of fields that represent the content on your page (or at least the fields that are configured to show up in the editform). Just remove the content.

Here's a picture for a 2013 environment: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for that I appreciate it, I am sorry but I am lost I know how to check that or get there, sorry I'm new at this!